# Xamarin getting wifi signal strength

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Is it possible in Xamarina to get information about the signal strength of all available wifi nearby? I am working on an application that collects and processes information about nearby wifi networks. I also want to get this information without having to connect to a given network.

FIX (The application was not allowed to perform the scan):

```
//Define permissions
private string[] permissions = new string[]
{
   Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation
};

//Permission check
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, permissions, 0);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the individual APIs for both Android and iOS? As far as I know, there isn't a way to get this information universally. It looks to be different based on the iOS device too.

Comment: I only mean Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android you can use the code below to get the Wifi Connections along with their strength from 0 to 100.

```
using Android.Net.Wifi;

...

var wifiMgr = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(WifiService);

var wifiList = wifiMgr.ScanResults;
foreach (var item in wifiList)
{
    var wifiLevel = WifiManager.CalculateSignalLevel(item.Level, 100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Wifi SSID: {item.Ssid} - Strengh: {wifiLevel}");
}
```

You will need to add these two permissions to the Manifest:

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  and `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`

And make sure you request authorization for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: The results container is empty, it seems to me that this is due to the lack of 
authorization request. I apologize for my awkwardness but this is one of my first contacts with Xamarin. How to make such a authorization request?

Comment: For the permissions look for Xamarin.Essentials package. One of the functionality is for handling the permissions. This link shows you how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid